# yii2-scroll-pager extension how apply in yii2

Tags: yii2, yii-extensions, yii2-advanced-app

yii2-scroll-pager  extension used but that extension not work.

[Extesion Link](https://github.com/kop/yii2-scroll-pager)

**View File -1: index.php**

```
echo ListView::widget( [
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,        
    'itemView' => '_item',
    'pager' => ['class' => \kop\y2sp\ScrollPager::className()]] );
```

**View File-2 : _item**

```
<?php $model->name;?><?php $model->age;?><?php $model->mobile;?>
```

**Controller File : SiteController.php**

```
$dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
            'query' => backend\models\Product::find(),

    ]);

    return $this->render('index', [
            'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    ]);
```

where is wrong in that code please hep guys

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27264287/scroll-pager-extension-in-yii2

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25045168/yii2-scroll-pager-with-overflow-scroll

Comment: vijay bhai mene ye try kar liye no result getting :(

Comment: Have you console log js errors?

Comment: do inspect element and check briefly in your console log

Comment: no error getting ajax not load

Comment: console log getting no error

Comment: no js error getting :(

Comment: scroll based not working :( i fix some issue like before ajax not work so that work but when click on "Load more items" then load more item  i want when scroll down that time load more items not a click base

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add this to your pager config

```
'triggerOffset'=>5

'pager' => [
  'class' => \kop\y2sp\ScrollPager::className(),
  'triggerOffset'=>5
 ]
```